# PHP Loop through array, find match and append property

Tags: php

I need to detect the current URL and set it an additional property if a match is found, so currently i'm looping through the object, if no match is found and the current property is an array then pass this array to itself.

So I have no way of knowing where about I am in the object to set the property, I need to somehow keep a reference of the keys? So I can then set the objects property.

Example object:

```
$example = [
    'home' => [
        'link' => 'index.php',
        'code' => 'home',
        'label' => 'Home'
    ],
    'cars' => [
        'link' => 'javascript:void(0)',
        'code' => 'used-cars',
        'label' => 'Used Cars',
        'void' => true,
        'subpages' => [
            [
                'link' => 'used-cars',
                'code' => 'used-cars',
                'label' => 'View all cars'
            ]
        ],
        'brands' => [
            'used' => [
                [
                    'link' => "/used/cars/audi",
                    'code' => "used-audi",
                    'label' => "Audi"
                ],
                [
                    'link' => "/used/cars/bmw",
                    'code' => "used-bmw",
                    'label' => "BMW"
                ],
                [
                    'link' => "/used/cars/chevrolet",
                    'code' => "used-chevrolet",
                    'label' => "Chevrolet"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

So, for example let's say i'm currently on 'used/cars/audi'. The array above containing that `link` should look like:

```
[
    'link' => "/used/cars/audi",
    'code' => "used-audi",
    'label' => "Audi"
    'current' = true
]
```

This is the code I have currently, how can I add the property to the correct place within the object during the loop?

```
private function findCurrent($links) {

    $request_uri = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0];
    if ($request_uri === '') {
        $request_uri = '/index.php';
    }

    foreach ($links as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($value) && $value == $request_uri) {

            // Set as current

            break;
        }

        // No match, but does it have children!?
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->findCurrent($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but this doesn't work"_ means what _exactly_? What is the current result/output?

Comment: foreach $links you mean you loop in used ?

Comment: maybe you just want $path to be passed in [as reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)?? Because now you modify it in the function, but don't return it.

Comment: also you are using this as a recousive function but never return anything.

Comment: The loop goes through the entire object, so basically i'm checking every single link.

Comment: @Jeff I don't want to return anything, I want to set a property within my original object when a match is found

Comment: and where are you expecting a result? in $path? (now that you've changed the code it doesn't make any sense anymore - at least not to me. The function does _nothing_ but calling itself..)

Comment: @Jeff ignore `$path`, if you look back at my question, you will see what i'm expecting. I need to loop through the entire object until I find a property with the link that matches. Once a match is found, I need to add a property to the same array which contains that link.

Comment: @MartynBall Did my answer do what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $usedNow = '/used/cars/bmw';
    $used = $example['cars']['brands']['used'];
    $links = array_combine(array_keys($used), array_column($used, 'link'));
    $index = array_search($usedNow, $links);
    $example['cars']['brands']['used'][$index]['current'] = true;
```

Comment: You know the exact path there, I can't hard-code the keys or anything as it could be anything.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that line: `$value == $request_uri` -> because `'void' => true` will fulfill that lazy comparison. Change that to

```
$value == $request_uri
```

Second: If you want to change the array from inside the function and from inside a foreach loop you need to pass it [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Here's a version of your function that works as I think you intended:

```
                // this '&' is important to pass the array as reference
function findCurrent(&$links) {
                               // dummy-data here for testing
    $request_uri = explode("?", "/used/cars/audi?test")[0];
    // original: $request_uri = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0];
    if ($request_uri === '') {
        $request_uri = '/index.php';
    }
                        // again, use $value as reference
    foreach ($links as $key => &$value) {
        #echo "now in $key<br>";

        if (isset($value) && $value === $request_uri) {
            // we found the correct entry, so return true
            return true;
        }

        // No match, but does it have children!?
        if (is_array($value)) {
            // if we found the link in this array,...
            if(findCurrent($value)) {
                // add the flag 'current'
                $value['current'] = true;   
                // and get out of the function
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

$success = findCurrent($links);

// testing if that array has changed as intended:
var_dump($links['cars']['brands']['used'][0]);

//  array(4) { 
//      ["link"]=> string(15) "/used/cars/audi" 
//      ["code"]=> string(9) "used-audi" 
//      ["label"]=> string(4) "Audi" 
//      ["current"]=> bool(true) 
//  }
```

Comment: But you are not adding the key as the op said. the array remain the same.